# How to add an integer value in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to use the value represented by an integer variable as a parameter to the `setText` function within `Edittext`.

However, the application is incompatible with this data type as `TextView` contains string type and value is an integer type.

Here is an example of this:

```
int value1 = extras.getInt("genscore");
     System.out.println("ammm"+value1);
     EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextHighScore);
     edittext.setText("I am here");       //This is working fine
     edittext.setText(value1);           //value1 is integer.
```

How can I correctly use the `setText` function with an integer as its parameter?

Comment: If you Googled, you would get the answer much faster

Comment: Its obvious that it doesn't work because it requires **`String`** value. go with Sarwar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 edittext.setText("" + value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this:-

```
edittext.setText(value1+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 textview.setText("" +value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = String.valueOf(integerValue);
edittext.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edittext.settext(String.valueOf(value1));
```

and you are good to go